# is there any way to create keys in new dictionary by combining the values of old dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dic_1 = {"First_names" : "alex,sam", "Last_Name" : "jones,junior"}
```

Create a dictionary from `dict_1` values like take the first name and last name and create a key.

for example:

```
new_dict = {"alex,jones" : "present", "sam,junior" : "absent"}
```

**desired result will be new_dict.**

Comment: What is the point of having such a `dict`?

Answer (score 1):

```
first_names = dic_1["First_names"].split(",")
last_names = dic_1["Last_Name"].split(",")

new_dict = {}

for first_name, last_name in zip(first_names, last_names):
    new_dict.setdefault(",".join([first_name, last_name]), None) # None/Absent/Present, whatever the default value needs to be
```